VSCode [File Watcher] watcherExclude syntax on remote Linux
I got this issue:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux#_visual-studio-code-is-unable-to-watch-for-file-changes-in-this-large-workspace-error-enospc
I looked at watched files and found that there are watchers for a bunch of stuff I don't need them for, for example .conda/, but when I went to try to get them excluded, it doesn't seem to work.
settings.json (user settings):
{"files.watcherExclude": {
        "/home/myhome/.conda": true,
}}

Server log:
[trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] Request to start watching: /home/myhome/.conda (excludes: /home/myhome/.vscode-server/extensions/**, includes: <all>, correlationId: <none>),/home/myhome/code-repo (excludes: /home/myhome/.vscode-server/extensions/**, includes: ["/home/myhome/.conda/**"], correlationId: <none>)
[trace] [File Watcher (node.js)] Started watching: '/home/myhome/.conda'

I formatted the above according to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/137872, but I've also tried **/.conda/**,  **/.conda/*/**, in watcherExclude and it does the same thing.

so this works for non-remote workspaces?
